# Error code - non static method requires a target

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My problem is an error while executing this code. This function work perfectly into an other utilisation.

This is my complete function code :

```
public List<t_heure_indemnite> GetAllHeureIndemnite(FirmMda f, bool justeActive)
{
    List<t_heure_indemnite> lHi = new List<t_heure_indemnite>();
    ce = new callistoEntities();
    try
    {
       var load = from i in ce.t_heure_indemnite
                  where i.FIRM == f.Name
                  select i;
       if (load != null)
       {
           List<t_heure_indemnite> liste = load.ToList();
           foreach (t_heure_indemnite h in liste)
           {
               lHi.Add(h);
           }
       }
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       MsgBox.Show(globale.AfficheErreur(e));
   }
   if (justeActive)
       return lHi.Where(i => i.ACTIVE == true).OrderBy(j => j.ORE).ToList();
   else
       return lHi.OrderBy(j => j.ORDRE).ToList();
}
```

Exception is present while executing : Non static method requires a target.
It appears when load.ToList is called.
It's called into public method and during an import traitement into an other list.

I don't know where is problem. Can you help me please ?

Comment: Pleae post a complete code-snipped including the actual method to be called and in which context it is called. Furthermore at which line does the error appear?

Comment: I'd expect this to be a *compile-time* error, rather than an exception. What *exactly* is the error - please give *all* the information you have. (As an aside, I'd *strongly* advise you to start following normal .NET naming conventions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can happen when your you use a null-reference variable in a lambda expression.  I would suggest to check if your variable ce.t_heure_indemnite is a null-reference.

```
if(ce.t_heure_indemnite != null)
```

Comment: It's not that, I've added a test and isn't null reference